# How to set two images beyond another one image?

Tags: html, css, image

I want to set two images beyond the another one image. Please find the below image i am trying to fix. But i couldn't to reach the solution.

```css
.main {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 width: 1100px;
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto;
}
.container-fluid {
    background-image: url("bluescreen1.png");
 background-size: 100% 15%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body class="main">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" style="z-index: 1;">
 <div class="col-sm-12">
  <img src="http://u.realgeeks.media/legacyplusrealty/email.jpg">
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  Some Text
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  <img src="http://u.realgeeks.media/legacyplusrealty/email.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width: 100%; height:320px; ">
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  <img src="http://u.realgeeks.media/legacyplusrealty/email.jpg" alt="Paris" style="width: 100%; height:320px; z-index: -100;">
 </div>
 
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

[image]

I want to the above format of design. The blue color image shows beyond the two images. but i couldn't to do it. Please review and guide me...

Comment: Use `z-index` in the blue image

Comment: i tried that also but there is no changes..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add `position:relative;` to every img as z-index only works with positioned elements

Comment: `position:absolute` is also considered "positioned element"

Comment: Thank you very much rakesh soni.  That's absolutely shows what i expect...

Comment: Yes I know but position: absolute with disturb the layout. As here we only want z-index to work so i suggest position relative